# how to use if statement in windows 7 batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I checked other examples here but I couldn't find anything.

my batch file is:

```
IF EXIST %2% (
python ./submit.pyc %1% -u username -p password %2%
) ELSE (
python ./submit.pyc %1% -u username -p password
)
```

The thing I want is I would like to check if there is a second argument in the command or not. like `c:/>myBatchFile arg1 arg2`

btw `arg1` must be typed in the command.

anyway, it says this:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\gcp>IF EXIST  (

C:\gcp>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather tou need:

```
IF EXIST "%~2" (
python ./submit.pyc %1 -u username -p password %2%
) ELSE (
python ./submit.pyc %1 -u username -p password
)
```

When accessing arguments only in the fromt % is set.

Comment: It is like that at the moment: `C:\gcp>IF EXIST "" (python ./submit.pyc 1 -u username -p password  )  ELSE (python ./submit.pyc 1 -u username -p password )` and it is doing its job I think. Is it normal being "" after the `EXIST` ?

Comment: @WhoCares - quotes are needed in case of path with space in it